# How to filter data and populate D3.js stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, stackedbarseries

I have data in csv in the format below which shows up in a d3 stacked bar graph with City as x axis, population as y axis and stacked on year.

```
Country City Year Population

US     Dallas 2010 1000
US     Dallas 2011 1200
UK     London 2010 700
UK     London 2011  850
US     Chicago  2010 1250
US     Chicago  2011  1300
```

I would like to have a Country dropdown and display only relevant data on the chart for the country selected.

### Below is the code snippet inside script tag:

```
  var outerWidth = 500;
  var outerHeight = 250;
  var margin = { left: 90, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40 };
  var barPadding = 0.2;
  var xColumn = "City";
  var yColumn = "Population";
  var colorColumn = "Year";
  var layerColumn = colorColumn;
  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  var yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");
  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
  // Use a modified SI formatter that uses "B" for Billion.
  var siFormat = d3.format("s");
  var customTickFormat = function (d){
    return siFormat(d).replace("G", "B");
  };
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(customTickFormat)
    .outerTickSize(0);
  function render(data){
    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data)
    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
      .values(function (d){ return d.values; });
    var layers = stack(nested);
    xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d){
      return d[xColumn];
    }));
    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(layers, function (layer){
        return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
          return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
      })
    ]);
    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
      return layer.key;
    }));
    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);
    var layerGroups = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layerGroups.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layerGroups.exit().remove();
    layerGroups.style("fill", function (d){
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });
    var bars = layerGroups.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
      return d.values;
    });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars
      .attr("x", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })
  }
  function type(d){
    d.Population = +d.Population;
    return d;
  }
  d3.csv("data.csv", type, render);
```

[Fiddle Link] (https://jsfiddle.net/GM71819/tcabb1ch/)

The challenge I am facing is with:
    1. Populate dropdown dynamically with Country name from Country field.
    2. Bind the data to chart after user selection in the dropdown.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By editing it into the question itself (not as a link)

Comment: @Glenn, edit your post with the chart's code. Not all, only the section about chart.

Comment: @Giordano Please see now

Comment: i can be contacted at gm71819@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these questions can help you:

[How to filter data using DC, D3, and Crossfilter to produce a bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109936/how-to-filter-data-using-dc-d3-and-crossfilter-to-produce-a-bar-chart)

and this:

[How to update data in stack bar chart in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186011/how-to-update-data-in-stack-bar-chart-in-d3)

Fiddle example filtering with combo: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2XG/8/

```
var e = document.getElementById("combo");
var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  
FilterDimension.filter(selection);
```

Comment: I have the chart working as long as filter is not needed. I am stuck with filtering the data on dropdown change event and updating the chart with new data.

Comment: Khelmo - I tried using the logic applied in first example. however i am unable to pass dropdown value to filterdimension. This is how it is done in the example, FilterDimension.filter("A"); But I would want something like this where mydll is dropdown id. FilterDimension.filter(document.getElementById("myddl").value);  But this doesnt seem to work

Comment: I put a combo in the example with filtering, it is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2XG/8/

Comment: This is very much relevant.Thanks Khelmo. Cant I perform the execution on dropdown change rather than button click?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Here is my code in this fiddle which is not functioning as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/GM71819/2wtpxpw5/

Comment: I am unable to replicate the functionality in stacked bar chart. Please help Khelmo

Comment: That jsfiddle is not complete, the html and js resources are missing. Please complete them. Also to enable d3 csv in jsfiddle, you would have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890836/loading-external-csv-file-in-jsfiddle. 
Also change the load type of javascript in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Khelmo- I tried accomplishing this using highcharts. 
Here is the fiddle link: jsfiddle.net/GM71819/9cczrxkv 
I am looking for building the stacked column chart with Client dropdown, Costfilter as radio buttons, Year on x-axis, stacked by function on metric value.
I thinking i am still missing something due to which the chart is not getting populated. Please let me know what's wrong here.